# Is there a way to block screen's multi display mode (-x) completely?

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen

I'd like to configure screen to only allow attaching to detached sessions and *not* to attached sessions, even if they're from the same user.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I couldn't find anything in the documentation and on the Internet, and the settings related to multiuser mode only seem to apply when there's more than user.

Answer (score 1):

`multiuser` is off by default.

`screen -r` will only attach to detached sessions, even for the same user.

Are you looking for a strict security control?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: At work we all use root (bad practice, I know...), so I don't want just anyone to be able to attach to my sessions. Another solution would be if there was some way to notify me when another user attaches to the same session, or if screen could ask me for confirmation first.

Comment: Ahaha -- you all use root == game over, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multiuser off`, but I don't think that affects the same user.